# Openshift Open ID Identity Provider with lookup mapping method

Tags: openshift, auth0, openshift-origin

I'm using an `OpenIDIdentityProvider` with `mappingMethod: claim` to authenticate admin users in the Openshift admin console. I'm using the auth0 service to authenticate users. The admin users are defined in an ansible playbook on deployment, effectively making the admin users hard-coded.

Is it possible to completely manage all admin and developer users using the `OpenIDIdentityProvider`, a `lookup` mapping method and adding something like `extraScopes: [roles]` to pull through the additional authorization roles into the authentication request? That would enable me to completely manage users and roles separately from the ansible playbook. **Next level bonus points for managing permissions on the authentication provider side.**

The Openshift documentation is very light on details for authentication / authorization outside of the default `mappingMethod: claim`.

Below is my identity provider json file for the claim-based mapping method:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "auth0",
      "challenge": false,
      "login": true,
      "mappingMethod": "claim",
      "kind": "OpenIDIdentityProvider",
      "clientID": "supersecretsauce",
      "clientSecret": "extrasupersecretsauce",
      "extraScopes": ["email", "profile"],
      "claims": {
        "id": [
          "email"
        ],
        "preferredUsername": [
          "email"
        ],
        "name": [
          "name"
        ],
        "email": [
          "email"
        ]
      },
      "urls": {
        "authorize": "https://fancypants.auth0.com/authorize",
        "token": "https://fancypants.auth0.com/oauth/token",
        "userInfo": "https://fancypants.auth0.com/userinfo"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To my simple mind the below would suffice for a working lookup-based mapping method with roles returned by the authentication provider:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "auth0",
      "challenge": false,
      "login": true,
      "mappingMethod": "lookup",
      "kind": "OpenIDIdentityProvider",
      "clientID": "supersecretsauce",
      "clientSecret": "extrasupersecretsauce",
      "extraScopes": ["email", "profile", "roles"],
      "claims": {
        "id": [
          "email"
        ],
        "preferredUsername": [
          "email"
        ],
        "name": [
          "name"
        ],
        "email": [
          "email"
        ],
        "role": [
          "roles"
        ]
      },
      "urls": {
        "authorize": "https://fancypants.auth0.com/authorize",
        "token": "https://fancypants.auth0.com/oauth/token",
        "userInfo": "https://fancypants.auth0.com/userinfo"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

An example of a functional role value would be `cluster-admin`.

Answer (score 1):

OpenID can only be used for authentication.  You are attempting to use it for both authentication and authorization.  This is not possible as roles and bindings are managed by Openshift - they cannot be delegated to an external service.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I gathered as much when I stumbled across this feature request https://trello.com/c/8olzeZH3

Comment: @Brown1 that card still only deals with authentication (group membership).  You would still have to bind roles to the groups in Openshift.

Comment: so openshift, as it stands, has no way to accept roles returned in the authentication token? For example, if the token included roles and groups that were named to match the roles and groups in openshift, openshift wouldn't accept those roles and groups. Because that was the intention, use roles and groups already defined within openshift, add them to users on the auth gateway side and return those roles and groups with the token.

Comment: @Brown1 tokens can assert your identity and group membership (but not roles).  That card is to make it so an identity provider would provide the group info (it only provides the identity information at this point).  Once that is implemented, you could bind the roles you want to various groups, and have auth0 assert the group membership.  If you wanted to hack around the limitation, you could create groups (via some script) that map 1:1 with roles (so group `admin` would be bound to the `admin` role).  This would let you essentially assert roles.